# Animate an image using jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css

I have an image of **mail** in the project. When i click on this image the mail should be send and  the **mail** image should animate ( the **mail** image should have some animation to know the mail is send), now the problem is i have no idea how to do it. So i don't have a code to post. I hope someone can get me an idea how to accomplish this task.

Below is the code to show how i had send mail:

```
protected void btnMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("maes@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add("rash@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
                mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("E:/textfile.txt");
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("maes@gmail.com", "krishnanav");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this a desktop application or web application?

Comment: Its a web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `<asp:LinkButton />`. It render's a `<a/>` with server side events

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnMail" OnClick="btnMail_Click" runat="server"><img src="/path/to/animated_image.gif" alt="mail" />Send</asp:LinkButton>
```

you have to use animated GIF image

Comment: Is that okay if i put image URL as image src?

Comment: sorry! can't understand.put here an example

Comment: like this? <asp:LinkButton runat="server" >
            <asp:Image imageurl="~/animated_image.gif" runat="server" />
        </asp:LinkButton>